# * in sscanf , * inside a []

Tags: c, scanf

I am learning about `sscanf` and came across a format string as below:

```
sscanf("%[^:]:%[^*=]%*[*=]%n",a,b,&c);
```

I understood the part `%[^:]` means scan till a `':'` is encountered and assign it to `a`.
`:` in format string mean match for a `':'`.

But

1. I understood that `%*d` mean suppress the assignment till a number is encountered. But then `%[^*=]`, what does the `*` inside the `[]` mean?
2. `%*[*=]`, is it like suppress the scanning till it encounters a `=`. If it is so, is it equivalent to `%[^=]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` inside square brackets is just a literal *.

This call to `sscanf` will match everything up to a * or = in the second directive, and assign the result to `b`.  Then the third directive will grab all * or = characters, and throw away the result.